# I am getting an error while running the migrate function in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

Up to yesterday, it was migrating fine but when I tried to make a migration for a new table, it displayed me this error.

I encountered this error while using: `php artisan migrate`

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 8 attempt to write a readonly database
(SQL: create table "answer" ("id" integer not null primary key autoincrement, 
"answer" text not null, "questionId" integer not null, "answerBy" text not null,
"postedAt" datetime not null, "created_at" datetime not null,
"updated_at" datetime not null))
```

AND

```
[PDOException]
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 8 attempt to write a readonly database
```

Not just while migrating but it won't allow me to do any other db related functions like `php artisan migrate:rollback` or `php artisan migrate:refresh`.
Any idea?

P.S. I am using ubuntu.

Comment: does this table already exists in your database? If yes..manually delete all the tables in your database, including `migrations` table and run the command once more...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct the permissions on the file that contains your SQLite file. It is unwritable by the user that runs migrations.

If you have command-line access, the article [How do I use chamod to change permissions?](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/cets/answers/chmod.html) will help you to set the readable permission on your SQLite database.

Answer (score 0):

What DBMS are you using?
verify the permissions the user of database